# Spring MVC upload file and send parsed data back

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, model-view-controller

I'm using Spring MVC for my web application. I'm implementing the file upload functionality. Following the tutorial, I was able to send the uploaded file to server through submit action of input type of "file". Then I parsed the uploaded xls file at server side and need to send parsed data (3 lists of custom objects) back to the same form to display. I sent the data back through ModelAttribute.

However, my problem now is that on the client side, I need to use those lists of custom objects in my javascript, but I can only retrieve each field of the custom objects through jstl tag library but I cannot get those custom objects in my javascript where I need them for other logic implementation.

Then I have tried an Ajax file upload plug-in because ajax call can return JSON response which objects can be used in Javascript. But cannot get the plug-in work properly.

I have been stuck on this problem for several days>.< Can anybody help on this? Either a solution on using ModelAttribute in Javascript or a Ajax call solution is ok. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you can't simply "flatten" your model objects into HTML and then access them from Javascript using the DOM API?

You said you return 3 lists of custom objects. So how about for each list, you build up a (hidden) HTML table, for example if you have a list of `Person` objects in a `ModelAttribute` called `people`:

```
<table id="people-table">
  <c:forEach var="person" items="${people}">
    <tr id="${person.id}>
      <td class="person-name">${person.name}</td>
      <td class="person-age">${person.age}</td>
      <td class="person-height">${person.height}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Now in your Javascript, you iterate over the rows in `people-table`, doing whatever you need to do - for example using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$("#people-table tr").each(
    var personId = $(this).attr("id");
    var personName = $(this).find("td.person-name").text();
    // etc, etc
    // Do something with these as required
);
```

It's possibly not the most elegant solution but it's easy to debug at least - you can always just inspect the `table` with Firebug etc to see if the data is correct, and from there you'll know whether to continue debugging the server-side or in the Javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, millhouse! I agree that flattening the model objects into HTML is an easy approach both to implement and debug. My only concern for this approach is that this will reveal some of my business logic in HTML which can be viewed by anyone from web page source. It would be great if the fields of my objects are assigned in javascript.

Comment: You could always remove the `table` from the DOM as the final step of your Javascript processing!?! :-)

Comment: Yes, removing the "table" serves the purpose. Thanks!